# Is there a way to save snapped windows in a windows 10 dual screen setup when reconnecting?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, windows-snap-assist

At work I've got a laptop with an extra screen at my desk. When I have to go to a meeting I unplug my laptop. Unfortunately when I do that, all my snapped windows are reset to my laptop screen. This is understandable because I only have one screen at this point. But when I come back to my desk and plug in the second screen my snapped windows are still only on my laptop.

Is there a way to "save" my snapped windows with the dual screen setup? So that when I get back after a meeting I don't have to re-adjust all the windows again.